# Android application takes more time to start up during first app launch with com.google.gms.google-services

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-multidex

I have an application that uses a lot of libraries. The application works fine with MultiDex. However, when I try to integrate Firebase SDK, the application takes a long time to load on first app launch for Android Devices < Android Lollipop.

On a Nexus 5 running 4.4.4, I'm experiencing a black screen that lasts about a minute before the application resumes as normal. It seems to be the MultiDex process. After some experimentation, re-integrating Firebase one step at a time, the issue first occurs when I `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

Any thoughts as to why this plugin adds so much bloat? Please do not comment on Instant Run. I've seen other stack overflow articles suggesting that, but Instant Run is not enabled, and this occurs whether I first launch from my computer, a debug apk, or a release apk.

Thanks in advance.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true
        javaMaxHeapSize = "4g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Firebase - https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'

    // Google Play Services - https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

    // SDKs
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I think your issue is mainly due to multi dexed app. Why are you using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0` generic version of play services? Can you add more specific library like `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0`?.

Comment: Unfortunately even if I remove Google Play Services, our Application will still require MultiDex.

Answer (score 0):

The [Set Up Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for Google Play Services needs to be corrected. Specifying  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` in your build dependencies is not good practice.  It adds *all* the Google Play and Firebase libraries to your app.  This increases build time, increases the size of your APK file, and frequently blows through the 64K method reference limit, forcing the use of Mulitdex.

Remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` and replace it with only the Play Services libraries that you need.  That may eliminate the need for Multidex and should improve your app's startup time.

Comment: Unfortunately even if I remove Google Play Services, our Application will still require MultiDex.